# Profile concurrent CUDA kernels

Tags: cuda

I am interested in getting memory performance counter of concurrent cuda kernels. I tried to use several nvprof options like, `--metrics all` and `--print-gpu-trace`. The output seems to indicate that kernels are not concurrent any more. And concurrent performance metrics of each kernel look almost exactly the same as those running each kernel alone. I think that these concurrent kernels ran in sequence. How could I get memory performance metrics counter of concurrent kernels, for example L2 cache?

Comment: see [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1015752/visual-profiler/profiling-deadloop-replay-kernel-with-nvprof-on-deep-neural-network/post/5205577/#5205577)  "*When you attempt to profile a metric or event with nvprof, all the concurrent kernels in the application are serialized*"  So its a limitation of `nvprof`, currently.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you Robert. Is there any way to get concurrent kernels' performance metrics?

Comment: I don't know of a way.

Comment: Also, this is mentioned in the documentation [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#collecting-remote-data) under "Metrics and Events".  That is admittedly a section on remote profiling, but the statement is true even in the ordinary case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do per-kernel profiling while having the kernels execute concurrently. You can however try the following workarounds:

1. Do only tracing. If you don't specify `--metrics` or `--events`, nvprof will only do a tracing run. In this case, nvprof will run the kernels concurrently, but you will only get kernel timings - not metric/event data.
2. If you own an NVIDIA Tesla GPU (as opposed to GeForce or Quadro), you can use the [CUPTI library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html)'s `cuptiSetEventCollectionMode(CUPTI_EVENT_COLLECTION_MODE_CONTINUOUS)` API to sample the metrics you want while the kernels are running concurrently. However, this will only allow you to get the aggregate metric/event data in that sampling interval - which means that you will not be able to correlate this data to individual kernels. CUPTI ships with a code sample called `event_sampling`, that demonstrates how to use this API.
3. Profile the metrics/events you want, and let the kernels serialize. For some metrics/events, you may be able to simply sum up the values to estimate behavior during concurrent execution.